Is my proof correct for showing subsequence convergence almost everywhere in $L^p$ spaces?
Let $1 < p < \infty$. Suppose a sequence of real-valued functions $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ in $L^p$. I want to show that there exists a subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ that converges to $f$ almost everywhere. Here’s my approach:

Assume by contradiction that no subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere.
Then, for some $\epsilon > 0$, every subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ has a set $E \subseteq X$ with $\mu(E) > \epsilon$ where $|f_{n_k}(x) - f(x)| \geq \epsilon$ for all $x \in E$ and infinitely many $k$.
Given convergence in $L^p$, we have $\|f_n - f\|_{L^p} \to 0$, implying $\|f_{n_k} - f\|_{L^p} < \delta$ for large $k$.
However, on $E$, $|f_{n_k}(x) - f(x)| \geq \epsilon$ infinitely often, so $\int_E |f_{n_k} - f|^p \, d\mu \geq \epsilon^p \cdot \mu(E) > \epsilon^{p+1}$, which contradicts $\|f_{n_k} - f\|_{L^p} \to 0$.

Does this argument correctly show the existence of an almost everywhere convergent subsequence? Thanks for any feedback!

what does it mean. converges in $L^p$

Convergence in $L^p$ means that a sequence of functions ${f_n}$ converges to a function $f$ in the sense of the $L^p$ norm. Specifically, ${f_n}$ converges to $f$ in $L^p$ if
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} |f_n - f|_{L^p} = 0,
$$
where the $L^p$ norm is defined as
$$
|f_n - f|_{L^p} = \left( \int_X |f_n(x) - f(x)|^p , d\mu(x) \right)^{1/p}.
$$

what is $X$ and what is $\mu(x)$, $d\mu(x)$?

In the context of $L^p$ spaces:

$X$: The domain on which the functions ${f_n}$ and $f$ are defined (e.g., an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$).
$\mu$: A measure on $X$,(often the Lebesgue measure).
$d\mu(x)$: The measure element associated with $\mu$, specifying integration with respect to $\mu$. For Lebesgue measure, we often write $d\mu(x) = dx$.


any suggestion on how to prove it

Your argument, if correct, would show that convergence in $L^p$ implies convergence almost everywhere. As for a suggestion on how to prove it, this is a standard result covered in nearly all texts on measure theory. If you don't want a spoiler, try to choose a good subsequence $f_{n_k}$ and then show that it converges to $f$.

Thanks. So "converges in Lp" means the limit as n goes to infinity of this crazy integral is equal to 0. Can I ask why doing all this?

Can you put the limit inside the integral? Or is that wrong

You're welcome! Yes, "converges in $L^p$" means that the limit of the $L^p$ norm (integral) goes to 0 as $n \to \infty$:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} |f_n - f|{L^p} = \lim{n \to \infty} \left( \int_X |f_n(x) - f(x)|^p , d\mu(x) \right)^{1/p} = 0.
$$
We can’t generally put the limit inside the integral since $L^p$ convergence doesn’t imply pointwise convergence. However, under specific conditions (like with the Monotone Convergence Theorem or Dominated Convergence Theorem), it’s possible to move the limit inside.
